# Go - wait for next item in a priority queue if empty

Tags: go, heap, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a priority queue to send json objects through a network socket based on priority. I am using the `container/heap` package to implement the queue. I came up with something like this:

```
for {
    if pq.Len() > 0 {
        item := heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
        jsonEncoder.Encode(&item)
    } else {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

Are there better ways to wait for a new item than just polling the priority queue?

Comment: Perhaps using a channel is better suited: https://gobyexample.com/channels

Comment: I'm not making this an answer as I can't come up with a piece of code to proof it but what about using channels in your implementation to signal when an item is pushed into the queue? Then you could have the user of the queue wait on the channel then pop off the queue when you get a signal on your channel.

Comment: @LeoCorrea I was in the process of writing an answer like that. It was a struct that embedded the heap and added a `newItem` channel. Then I realized you may as well just get rid of that extra crap and use the channel directly. Why tell someone "now you can pop" instead of just popping the item automatically by sending it through the channel? There are blocking mechanisms built in as well so it's not like you need these sleeps or waits or anything.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal how do you impose priority on that implementation then?

Comment: @LeoCorrea oh yeah idk what I'm thinking. My original design is what he wants though I don't actually really like that. I think signalling on a channel to tell someone it can pop a queue is a hack. It's using a push/pull mechanism to accomplish the goal of pulling. Instead I think a better idea would be to reverse the thing and push, maintain an ordered list, and push the item you want to dequeue to whatever code uses it.

Comment: @LeoCorrea Thank you. If I create a buffered channel that gets a "true" every time an item was pushed i could range on that channel in the pop routine. This would solve my problem i think.

Comment: Yeah no offense but that design sucks... It's not idiomatic at all. If your code is reading from channel to know when it can and cannot read from a queue then obviously you've done something wrong. Get rid of your queue and learn to make better use of channels. Your 'queue' thing should just push the data through a channel as it becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use a couple a queuing goroutine. Starting with the data structures in the [PriorityQueue example](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#Init), I'd build a function like this:

http://play.golang.org/p/hcNFX8ehBW

```
func queue(in <-chan *Item, out chan<- *Item) {
    // Make us a queue!
    pq := make(PriorityQueue, 0)
    heap.Init(&pq)

    var currentItem *Item       // Our item "in hand"
    var currentIn = in          // Current input channel (may be nil sometimes)
    var currentOut chan<- *Item // Current output channel (starts nil until we have something)

    defer close(out)

    for {
        select {
        // Read from the input
        case item, ok := <-currentIn:
            if !ok {
                // The input has been closed. Don't keep trying to read it
                currentIn = nil
                // If there's nothing pending to write, we're done
                if currentItem == nil {
                    return
                }
                continue
            }

            // Were we holding something to write? Put it back.
            if currentItem != nil {
                heap.Push(&pq, currentItem)
            }

            // Put our new thing on the queue
            heap.Push(&pq, item)

            // Turn on the output queue if it's not turned on
            currentOut = out

            // Grab our best item. We know there's at least one. We just put it there.
            currentItem = heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)

            // Write to the output
        case currentOut <- currentItem:
            // OK, we wrote. Is there anything else?
            if len(pq) > 0 {
                // Hold onto it for next time
                currentItem = heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
            } else {
                // Oh well, nothing to write. Is the input stream done?
                if currentIn == nil {
                    // Then we're done
                    return
                }

                // Otherwise, turn off the output stream for now.
                currentItem = nil
                currentOut = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of using it:

```
func main() {
    // Some items and their priorities.
    items := map[string]int{
        "banana": 3, "apple": 2, "pear": 4,
    }

    in := make(chan *Item, 10) // Big input buffer and unbuffered output should give best sort ordering.
    out := make(chan *Item)    // But the system will "work" for any particular values

    // Start the queuing engine!
    go queue(in, out)

    // Stick some stuff on in another goroutine
    go func() {
        i := 0
        for value, priority := range items {
            in <- &Item{
                value:    value,
                priority: priority,
                index:    i,
            }
            i++
        }
        close(in)
    }()

    // Read the results
    for item := range out {
        fmt.Printf("%.2d:%s ", item.priority, item.value)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Note that if you run this example, the order will be a little different every time. That's of course expected. It depends on exactly how fast the input and output channels run.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use [`sync.Cond`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond):

> Cond implements a condition variable, a rendezvous point for goroutines waiting for or announcing the occurrence of an event.

An example from the package could be amended as follows (for the consumer):

```
c.L.Lock()
for heap.Len() == 0 {
    c.Wait() // Will wait until signalled by pushing routine
}
item := heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
c.L.Unlock()
// Do stuff with the item
```

And producer could simply do:

```
c.L.Lock()
heap.Push(x)
c.L.Unlock()
c.Signal()
```

(Wrapping these  in functions and using defers might be a good idea.)

Here is an example of thread-safe (naive) heap which pop method waits until item is available:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "sync"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
)

type Heap struct {
    b []int
    c *sync.Cond
}

func NewHeap() *Heap {
    return &Heap{c: sync.NewCond(new(sync.Mutex))}
}

// Pop (waits until anything available)
func (h *Heap) Pop() int {
    h.c.L.Lock()
    defer h.c.L.Unlock()
    for len(h.b) == 0 {
        h.c.Wait()
    }
    // There is definitely something in there
    x := h.b[len(h.b)-1]
    h.b = h.b[:len(h.b)-1]
    return x
}

func (h *Heap) Push(x int) {
    defer h.c.Signal() // will wake up a popper
    h.c.L.Lock()
    defer h.c.L.Unlock()
    // Add and sort to maintain priority (not really how the heap works)
    h.b = append(h.b, x)
    sort.Ints(h.b)
}

func main() {
    heap := NewHeap()

    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(time.Second) {
            for n := 0; n < 3; n++ {
                x := rand.Intn(100)
                fmt.Println("push:", x)
                heap.Push(x)
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        item := heap.Pop()
        fmt.Println("pop: ", item)
    }
}
```

(Note this is not working in playground because of the `for range time.Tick` loop. Run it locally.)

Comment: Seems that your code is not working on play.golang.org.

Comment: You're correct, edited answer with a comment. It doesn't work on playground because of the infinite `for range time.Tick` loop and the way playground is handling time (see http://blog.golang.org/playground). This simple example fail to run either: http://play.golang.org/p/2LXDXdEBxu